# PHP how to check if parent of DOM object exist

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, parent-child

I need to get all of the parents of each node. Here's a part of my code given below:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument; 
    $dom->loadHTMLfile($myvar);
    $allElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

    foreach($allElements as $element){
        print $element->tagName;
        if(get_parent_class($element) !== NULL){
            print ' parent is '.$element->parentNode->tagName.'<br>';
        }
        else{
            print '<br>';
        }
    }
```

The $myvar = 'sample.html' and it looks like this:

```
   <html>



<body>
    <div id="mango">
        This is the mango div. It has some text and a form too.
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" value="Yahoo" />
            <input type="text" name="last_name" value="Bingo" />
        </form>

        <table class="inner">
            <tr><td>WEW</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <table id="data" class="outer">
        <tr><td>Happy</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Sad</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Grumpy</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Horny</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Fappy</td><td>Sky</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
    </html>
```

**The first few lines of the output looks like this:**
sample.html
html
Notice: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$tagName in C:\xampp\htdocs\tut\form.php on line 27
parent is 
body parent is html
div parent is body

Somehow it still enters the if clause when `$element = <html>`. I want it not to enter the if statement since it doesn't have a parent node. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

After seeing your html, and trying it out, I think I have a simple solution for you:

`if(!empty($element->parentNode->tagName))`

Try that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I tried both of them but neither is working. I posted the html source code.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect my answer after seeing your html code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceOf`:

```
if ($element->parentNode instanceOf DOMElement) {
```

The parent node of the document element is the document node itself. So it is a DOMDocument, a DOMNode but not a DOMElement.